# JSON-based build tool?

Tags: json, maven, ant, build, makefile

I'm looking for a build tool (such as ant, maven, make, etc.) that uses JSON-based configuration files?

Does such a tool exist?

Comment: since you include ANT and Maven we must assume you're building java code.

Comment: I'm not building a Java app and I don't understand why JSON should be more of an horror compared to XML. Other way around, I guess ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think what you're really looking for is a build tool that doesn't force you to configure everything in XML?

In that case your best bet is [Gradle](http://gradle.org/). It doesn't have the same sort of adoption as [ANT](http://ant.apache.org/) or [Maven](http://maven.apache.org/), but does have the advantage of learning lessons from both.

I would advise you to beware of straying from standard build tooling... It makes life tougher for others attempting to build your code. This is something Gradle solved by providing a [build wrapper](http://gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/gradle_wrapper.html).

Answer (score 6):

Nokia/Qt just announced their "QBS" build system, which is JSON-based, and is actually a build engine intended for easy adoption by IDEs (a principal reason for adopting JSON).

[Introducing qbs](http://labs.qt.nokia.com/2012/02/15/introducing-qbs)

Rather than a "pre-make" generator of Makefiles/vcprojs/etc. (like CMake and QMake, etc.), qbs is intended to actually be the build engine.

Answer (score 5):

Google turned up [Gaudi](https://github.com/stpettersens/Gaudi) though it is still in the early phases.

Comment: Does it relate with google's current early phase build tool 'bazel'? If yes, how?